# "coroutine local" variables in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Java has ThreadLocal variables that are nice for running parallel operations without stepping on other threads or per-loop allocations, for example OpenCV uses `videoCapture.retrieve(image)`, and "image" could be a threadlocal variable.

Does Kotlin have any sense of "coroutine-local" variables?  If I wanted to take their counter example but have a counter per coroutine, how would I do that?

```
for (i in 1..1_000_000)
    thread(start = true) {
       c.addAndGet(i)
    }
```

Comment: I think you can use the `CoroutineContext`: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/-coroutine-context/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are looking for `ThreadLocal` as a performance optimization, to make sure that each thread gets it own copy of some temporary object, then you should continue using `ThreadLocal` for that purpose. There can be much more coroutines than threads, and keeping a copy of some temporary object for each coroutine may do more harm than good.

If you are looking for `ThreadLocal` as a way to pass some context around method invocation, then I strongly suggest to consider explicitly passing this context into your functions or using some dependency injection framework to do that.

If you have a rare case where you indeed need to pass some context around, but for some technical reason you cannot pass it explicitly nor you can use DI (that is where you would have used `ThreadLocal` with threads), you can use `CoroutineContext` with coroutines. The steps are:

Define your own coroutine context element class using the following template:

```
class MyContextElement : AbstractCoroutineContextElement(MyContextElement) {
    companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<MyContextElement>
    // you state/code is here
}
```

Create an instance of your element and pass it to the coroutine builder when you start your coroutine. The following example uses `launch` coroutine builder, but it works with all of them (`async`, `produce`, `actor`, etc)

```
launch(MyContextElement()) {
    // the code of your coroutine
}
```

You can combine your context with other context elements using `+` operators (see ["Combining Contexts" in the guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#combining-contexts) for details)

From inside your coroutine code you can always retrieve your element from the `coroutineContext`. All the standard builders bring the [CoroutineScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/-coroutine-scope/index.html) instance into their scope, which makes its `coroutineContext` property available. If you are deep in the call stack of suspending functions, then you can define your own `coroutineContext()` helper function to retrieve the current context until it makes its way into the standard library in one of the future updates. See [KT-17609](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17609) for details.

With the `coroutineScope` in hand, it is easy to retrieve your element:

```
val myElement = coroutineScope[MyContextElement]
```

Answer (score 1):

For those stumbling upon this question nowadays, it seems that the syntax has changed a bit:

```
class MyContextElement : AbstractCoroutineContextElement(MyContextElement), CoroutineContext.Element {
    override val key = Key

    companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<KCallScope>

}
```

In order to be `CoroutineContext.Key` you now need to implement `CoroutineContext.Element`, which requires you to implement `key` getter.